# How to select number of record based on a count in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return the X number of records in a table based on the count of records in a subquery.

For example, if the TOP 80 PERCENT of records in MYTABLE equals 275 records, then I want to select 275 records from another table.

Can this be done with just plain dynamic SQL, and without creating variables etc?

My predecessor wrote something like this:

```
DECLARE @RecordVariable int

SET @RecordVariable =
(SELECT COUNT(*) * .8 
FROM MYTABLE)

SELECT TOP (@RecordVariable) *
FROM
MYOTHERTABLE
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? seems pretty simple to me...

Comment: should be possible to just put the count-select into the TOP condition

Comment: Hey Brian... I think one of these somber your problem, no?

Answer (score 6):

You can nest the query within the `TOP ()`

```
SELECT TOP (Select cast(count(*)*.8 as int) From MYTABLE) *
FROM MYOTHERTABLE
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

> **EDIT - Speed-Up Random Select**

Here is one method to increase the speed using TABLESAMPLE

```
SELECT TOP (Select cast(count(*)*.8 as int) From MYTABLE) *
FROM MYOTHERTABLE
TABLESAMPLE (10000 ROWS)  -- could be (50 PERCENT)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

This will essentially take a random block of 100,000 rows (change as desired), and then return top N order by NewID()

Comment: John, this seems to work. (Unfortunately, for some reason, it's super slow for me.)

Comment: @BrianBattles Curios.  How fast is the count(*) ?  Response without the NewID()  ?

Comment: @BrianBattles Honestly, is should be no different than your original.  I will run some tests on my end

Comment: @BrianBattles You are CORRECT.  There is a noticable differance  between a HARD Value and either a calculated variable or nested query.  The calculated variable and nested query perform the same.

Comment: @BrianBattles FYI without Order By NewID()  ...  All just as fast

Comment: Yes, I think the NEWID() slows it down appreciably, John.

Comment: @BrianBattles I've tested on a smaller table as well.  All good and responsive.  The larger one get the performance hit from NewID() because it has to resolve for each record

Comment: @BrianBattles See Edit regarding TABLESAMPLE

Comment: @BrianBattles To be clear, TABLESAMPLE will retrieve random pages (not rows)

Comment: 1 from me for table-sample @JohnCappelletti. Good idea, though since there is an order by it probably isn't the desired result (but then again, newid isn't really a telling ordering column like a date or something). Either way, good educational point.

Comment: @scsimon Agreed.  Personally I prefer Stratified Sampling, but that is equal parts Art and Science.  That said, With TableSample, the final result is a random set within a random set of pages.

Answer (score 6):

No need for dynamic SQL either, I wouldn't think.

```
select top (select cast((count(*) * .8)as int) from YourTable) 
* from YourTable
order by NEWID()
```